# Database on USB device

Tags: sql, mariadb

Currently I use SQLite on USB storage for archival and backup of data. But I like to upgrade the whole application on a real DBMS most likely MariaDB.

Edit: What I currently do is to open/create a SQLite file on the USB drive, access and have the option to access the original database in parallel.

Is there any option to hang in an exported database in an already running DBMS instance?

Thanks

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/portable-mariadb/

Comment: Thank you Tarek. I'm just wondering, if I have to start another server instance? I see my question is incomplete...

Comment: An instance of MariaDB can have any number of databases in it.  And be accessed simultaneously by any number of connections accessing any or all of the databases.

Comment: Right. But as far as I see, there is no way to have a running instance, plugin a USB drive and 'mount' the databases from that drive. I know that this is not a common use case, but how would I backup specific data on an external storage?

Comment: you could dump the database and write it to your usb device: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysqldump/

Answer (score 0):

I currently run a small database with MariaDB RDBMS. The database files are kept on USB drive, which I keep plugged in permanently.

If I understand correctly OP wants to know if it would be possible to have a database on the main drive and be able to configure the RDBMS to also see the backup database when the pendrive is plugged in.

The answer is "Possible, but impractical".

Why:

- To work on files form outside of the data directory one [needs to create sybolic links to those files IN the data directory](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/does-mariadb-support-multiple-data-directories-within-a-single-instance/)
- When the pendrive is not plugged in, the symlinks still exist and RDBMS might error out, especially when there is a query trying to acces that data.
- If one wants to re-create the links on usb stick insert, then to use those the whole RDBMS must be restarted.

A much more robust, convenient and portable solution would be to

- keep the backup base in SQLite and...
- have a script that copies data from MariaDB to SQLite, for example in Python.
  Such a script can then be set up to either run periodically and exit gracefully when pendrive is not inserted, or to be ran on detection of pendrive.

Another way to backup data is to just use mysqldump, as pointed out in comments to Original Question, but simple as it may be it takes away the ability to query the backup data without the (sometimes lengthy) process if re-importing.